# phpMyAdmin import csv into database error

Tags: csv, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a csv file into a database without having defined a table in it but I got an error. I did it one week earlier but now I am not able to import the same csv file.

[image]

When I import the csv file the new table contains only one column and the the first letter is missing in the first row.

This is the csv file:

[image]

The imported scv looks like this

[image]

How can I solve this?

[I am using phpMyAdmin from web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dQkr.png)

Comment: How exactly do you import? What does the import specification or import options set look like?